# Unittest: How to ensure type equality, not just value equality?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

In python 2.7 unittest framework,

```
self.assertEquals(u"a","a")
```

does not fail.

How do I compare the strings in unittest so that `str` is not equal to `unicode`?

I don't want to replace every

```
self.assertEquals(foo(...),"a")
```

with

```
v = foo(...)
self.assertEquals(type(v),str)
self.assertEquals(v,"a")
```

I cannot use [`addTypeEqualityFunc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc) because my function will be called only *if two objects are of exactly the same typeobj*, so it is not called precisely in the case when I *want* it to be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can easily attach additional tests to a unit testsuit by *defining* tests oneself in the test class (or even better, define a super class you subclass for every testsuite). A generic test that would check type and equality at the same time would be the following:

```
def assertEqualsValType(self,obj1,obj2,msg=None):
    self.assertEquals(type(obj1),type(obj2),msg)
    self.assertEquals(obj1,obj2,msg)
```

Or maybe shorter:

```
def assertEqualsValType(self,obj1,obj2,msg=None): #alternative
    self.assertEquals((type(obj1),obj1),(type(obj2),obj2),msg)
```

The function checks whether both given objects are equal by type and value. (These are not specialized to string objects per se, but evidently if you need a more sophisticated test, you can rewrite it). In other words you hide complexity you would have checked by using several tests into one test.

And then call the function `self.assertEqualsValType('a',u'a')` which will fail. Furthermore by keeping the test as generic as possible you can find other uses for it: for instance `self.assertEqualsValType(2,2.0)` will fail as well.

Potentially you can also rewrite the above function to give more informative messages, etc.

This could thus be a stub to begin your own more advanced unit tests. For instance:

```
class BaseUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def assertEqualsValType(self,obj1,obj2,msg=None):
        self.assertEquals(type(obj1),type(obj2),msg)
        self.assertEquals(obj1,obj2,msg)

    def assertBetweenEqual(self, value, min_value, max_value):
        self.assertGreaterEqual(value, min_value)
        self.assertLessEqual(value, max_value)

    def assertFoo(self,para,meters):
        #...
        pass
```

And the you can subclass your entire testbase from these.